# object is not a function in menuitem

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-html5, cocos2d-js

I'm getting this error message from Chrome Console, when I push a Menu item that tries to change the scene:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function CCMenuItem.js:174
cc.MenuItem.cc.Node.extend.activate CCMenuItem.js:174
cc.MenuItemLabel.cc.MenuItem.extend.activate CCMenuItem.js:333
(anonymous function) CCClass.js:138
cc.Menu.cc.Layer.extend.onTouchEnded CCMenu.js:442
cc.TouchDispatcher.cc.Class.extend.touches CCTouchDispatcher.js:376
cc.TouchDispatcher.cc.Class.extend.touchesEnded CCTouchDispatcher.js:508
cc.ProcessMouseupEvent CCTouchDispatcher.js:630
(anonymous function)
```

this is my code from the menu:

```
var menuItem1 = new cc.MenuItemFont.create("Play",this,this.onPlay);
var size = cc.Director.getInstance().getWinSize();
menuItem1.setPosition(new cc.Point(size.width/2,size.height/2+50));

var menu = cc.Menu.create(menuItem1);

menu.setPosition(new cc.Point(0,0));

this.addChild(menu);
```

And the function of menuitem1:

```
onPlay:function(){
    //cc.log("==onplay clicked");
    //var director = cc.Director.getInstance();
    //director.replaceScene(new MainLayer());
}
```

Comment: This is cocos2d-js, right? If so please don't use cocos2d-iphone tag as that is a different engine.

Comment: Cocos2d-html and -js tags has almost no followers

Comment: That's because they're less popular. You probably won't get help from users of more popular but unrelated tags. If SO worked that way, we'd all tag most questions with 'programming'. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to swap `this` and `this.onPlay`:

`var menuItem1 = new cc.MenuItemFont.create("Play",this.onPlay,this);`

`Create` function looks like this:

`cc.MenuItemFont.create = function (value, callback, target) {
    return new cc.MenuItemFont(value, callback, target);
};`